# Scringo twitter integration callback URL configuration

Tags: twitter, integration, scringo

I have followed the directions to a tee from http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/popular/connect-to-social-networks/ to integrate Twitter with Scringo.

I'm using a callback URL of the form (http://www.example.com). On Twitter, access is set to read only and "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" is checked. Consumer key and secret are set in assets/scringo.properties file.

My error message is

```
01-30 17:25:53.937: E/Scringo(1067): Scringo Twitter error: Did you configure the Callback URL in your Twitter app settings page (dev.twitter.com)
```

I don't really think my code is the cause, because even the main Scringo samples from Scringo's site don't work with my properties file.

I think it's worth mentioning that I have successfully integrated Facebook into my Scringo application, so any considerations about network are a not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are facing this issue because of a recent twitter change. mentioned here https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239

To fix this you need to change twitter4j lib version to 3.0.5 [Scringo libs folder will have twitter4j-core-3.0.4.jar]. I am able to resolve my app twitter integration issue with this change.